# Match every JSON (stringified) key and value using one regex group

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I tried `/("(?:[^\"]|\")*?")/g`

```
const string = `[
 {
  "name": "total_4_dials_time",
  "type": "transform",
  "source": "long total_nodes = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nMap res = [:];\nres[\"nodes\"] = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nlong millis = System.currentTimeMillis();\nres[\"@time\"] = millis;\nreturn res;"
 }
]`;

const regexJSONKeysAndValues = new RegExp('("(?:[^\"]|\")*?")', 'g');
const result = string.match(regexJSONKeysAndValues);
console.log(result);
```

And got the "source" value splitted into three strings where is \". I don't need the "source" value splitted.

```
[
 '"name"',
 '"total_4_dials_time"',
 '"type"',
 '"transform"',
 '"source"',
 '"long total_nodes = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nMap res = [:];\nres["',
 '"] = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nlong millis = System.currentTimeMillis();\nres["',
 '"] = millis;\nreturn res;"' 
]
```

What regex to use to achieve the following result?

```
[ 
'"name"',
 '"total_4_dials_time"',
 '"type"',
 '"transform"',
 '"source"',
 '"long total_nodes = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nMap res = [:];\nres["nodes"] = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nlong millis = System.currentTimeMillis();\nres["@time"] = millis;return res;"'
 ]
```

Here is my regex playground with an example https://regex101.com/r/YTzXaV/4

I need this for my custom [ace editor](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace) mode. Ace editor value is a string, not an object. The values which contain \n must be wrapped with triple-quotes. For example,

```
const string = `[
  {
    "name": "total_4_dials_time",
    "type": "transform",
    "source": "long total_nodes = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nMap res = [:];\nres['nodes'] = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nlong millis = System.currentTimeMillis();\nres['@time'] = millis;\nreturn res;"
  }
]`;

const unfoldMultiLineString = (string = '') => {
  const regexJSONKeysAndValues = new RegExp('("(?:[^\"]|\")*?")', 'g');

  return string.replace(regexJSONKeysAndValues, (match, value) => {
    const areNewLines = value.includes('\n');
    if (areNewLines) {
      return `"""\n${value.slice(1, value.length - 1)}\n"""`;
    }

    return value;
  });
};

console.log(unfoldMultiLineString(string));
```

Result:

```
[
 {
  "name": "total_4_dials_time",
  "type": "transform",
  "source": """
long total_nodes = data.nodestats._nodes.total;
Map res = [:];
res['nodes'] = data.nodestats._nodes.total;
long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
res['@time'] = millis;
return res;
"""
 }
]
```

It doesn't work if "source" value contains double quotes though.

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse json?

Comment: @solarc I need this for my custom ace editor mode. Ace editor value is a string, not an object.

Comment: Can you stringify the keys and values back after parsing the json? that way you get `"name"` instead of `name` and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `JSON.parse` if you double-escape the backslashes, so `\` => `\\`:

```js
const string = `[
 {
  "name": "total_4_dials_time",
  "type": "transform",
  "source": "long total_nodes = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\\nMap res = [:];\\nres['nodes'] = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\\nlong millis = System.currentTimeMillis();\\nres['@time'] = millis;\\nreturn res;"
 }
]`;

const parsed = JSON.parse(string);

const result = Object.keys(parsed[0]).flatMap(k => [k, parsed[0][k]]).map(JSON.stringify);
console.log(result);
```

Result:

```
[
  "\"name\"",
  "\"total_4_dials_time\"",
  "\"type\"",
  "\"transform\"",
  "\"source\"",
  "\"long total_nodes = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\\nMap res = [:];\\nres['nodes'] = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\\nlong millis = System.currentTimeMillis();\\nres['@time'] = millis;\\nreturn res;\""
]
```

Comment: Sorry, I messed up my example. I updated the post. Look at the source value. There should be double-quotes, for example, `res[\"nodes\"]` not single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I don't completely understand what you're looking for, let's look if this helps:

```js
function pythonify(obj) {
    let out = Object
        .entries(obj)
        .map(([k, v]) => {
            if (typeof v === 'string' && v.includes('\n'))
                v = '"""\n' + v + '\n"""';
            else
                v = JSON.stringify(v)
            return '    ' + JSON.stringify(k) + ': ' + v;
        });
    return '{\n' + out.join(',\n') + '\n}'
}

//

const string = String.raw`[
 {
  "name": "total_4_dials_time",
  "type": "transform",
  "source": "long total_nodes = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nMap res = [:];\nres[\"nodes\"] = data.nodestats._nodes.total;\nlong millis = System.currentTimeMillis();\nres[\"@time\"] = millis;\nreturn res;"
 }
]`;


console.log(pythonify(JSON.parse(string)[0]))
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `String.raw`.

Answer (score 0):

i just went back to your https://regex101.com/r/YTzXaV/4 example and escaped the double quotes that are also escaped in your code example and used the following regex:

- ("(?:[^\"]|\")*?[^\\]")

The only part i added being [^\\] so that the last double quote must be preceded by any character that is not a backslash